# How can I allow a localhost SSL cert when using localhost to redirect a domain?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, localhost, hosts-file

At the moment I have in my hosts file a custom link for facebook.com which leads to 127.0.0.1. I wanted this so when I go to facebook.com, it runs a php script on localhost which redirects to messenger.com (because I use messenger but not facebook) and I often type facebook.com from time to time when I mean to go to messenger.com, although when it runs through I get an error from chrome saying "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID". I've installed the localhost certificate but it still won't allow access. Hopefully someone has an idea of how to fix this and allow it to go through.

Thanks!

Comment: If your certificate is for “localhost”, it isn’t for “facebook.com” or “www.facebook.com”.

Comment: Then how would I go about getting it to allow access, so it can redirect to localhost?

Comment: The easiest way is not to do all that but instead write a Userscript for Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey.

Comment: @DanielB It works this way, takes a while for the script to redirect but it's better than having to retype the url. Thanks :)